# How do you use bootstrap 3 pagination with php MVC using Netbeans?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, pagination

I am currently creating a small application which features a lot of content, I want to make that content appear in an organised manner and the best way I can see this is using Pagination. I have had a look through the bootstrap documentation however I cannot work it out how I am going to get this to work as I have never used it before.

Model:

```
public function showFilms($UserID){

    //declare new film array
    $film = array();

    //SQL Query Selecting equivalent information to be displayed
    $sqlQuery = 'SELECT FilmID, Title, Director,YearofRelease, Genre, Image, MainActor, MainActor1, MainActor2, Synopsis FROM films WHERE User ="' . $UserID . '" ORDER BY Title DESC';

    // prepare a PDO statement
    $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuery);
    // Execute PDO statement
    $statement->execute();

    // While loop fetches each row matching query
    while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
        $film[] = array('FilmID' => $row['FilmID'],
            'Title' => $row['Title'],
            'User' => $UserID,
            'Director' => $row['Director'],
            'YearofRelease' => $row['YearofRelease'],
            'Genre' => $row['Genre'],
            'Image' => $row['Image'],
            'MainActor' => $row['MainActor'],
            'MainActor1' => $row['MainActor1'],
            'MainActor2' => $row['MainActor2'],
            'Synopsis'=> $row['Synopsis']
        );

    }
    //returning film array
    return $film;

}
```

View:

```
<div id="FilmArea">
    <!-- Count for Films -->
    <?php
    if (count($film)) {
        ?>
        <br>
        <!-- Displaying each entry using count of hidden list value of id of entry -->
        <?php foreach ($film as $list): ?>
            <!-- Panel Start -->
            <div class="panel panel-info">

                <!-- Panel Header -->
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 20px; color: black; ">
                       <?= ( $list['Title']) ?>  <small> Directed By : <?= ( $list['Director']) ?></small>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <!-- Panel Body -->
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id='dvdHolder'>
                        <?= ($list['Image'] <> "" ? "<img style='max-width:200px; max-height:200px;' src='Images/{$list['Image']}'/>" : "") ?>
                    </div>
                    <div id='dvdInfo'>
                        <p style='font-weight: bold;'> Year Released :  <?= ( $list['YearofRelease']) ?></p>
                        <p style='font-weight: bold;'> Film Genre :  <?= ($list['Genre'] ) ?></p>
                        <p style="font-weight: bold;"> Starring : <?= ($list['MainActor']) ?> , <?= ($list['MainActor1']) ?> , <?= ($list['MainActor2']) ?> </p>
                        <p style='font-weight: bold;'> Synopsis :  <?= ($list['Synopsis'] ) ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Entry -->
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <!-- Else show this message if user has no entries -->
        <?php
    }else {
        ?>
        <p><b>No Films Added yet!</b></p>
    <?php } ?>  
</div>
```

Controller:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once('Model/UserDataSet.php');
require_once('Model/FilmDataSet.php');

$view = new stdClass();
$view->pageTitle = 'My Vault';




$aa = new FilmDataSet();
$film = array();
$film = $aa->showFilms($_SESSION['Email']);



require_once('View/home.phtml');
```

[Screenshot of Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rvNC.png)

Any help or information on how I can implement pagination into my application would be great.

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: Hi I am using phpMyAdmin